# Rating feature - Change "Unlike" to "Liked"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rating

I've enabled the rating feature and use the likes system in my SharePoint item.

When a user clicks the "Like" button, the button is changed to "Unlike".

The "Unlike" button looks awkward to me. I would like to know if it is possible to simply change the wording to "Liked" instead.

Comment: You can use Client side rendering using JSLink to change the look and feel of your like/unlike field. Check example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185470/custom-like-button-in-sharepoint-list

Comment: There is no OOTB method to simply change the wording to "Liked".